# Filter files with name

Tags: powershell

I need some advise,
Have many files with names like this

```
2011-05-02_11-10-00_1092_25240
2021-03-01_14-05-00_5008_537540
2011-04-02_13-00-00_2001_537540
2014-03-02_21-00-00_1029_239440
```

i need find all files with 1 in position 21,

```
2011-05-02_11-10-00_1092_25240
2014-03-02_21-00-00_1029_239440
```

thanks

Comment: Try ```$filenames | where-object { $_[20] -eq "1" };``` (note character positions are zero-indexed so ```$_[20]``` is the 21st character in the string). If you're still stuck it would be useful if you can post any code you've already written so we can give specific help with your script...

Answer (score 0):

Runs fine for me :

```
$filenames | Where-Object { $_ -match "^.{20}1"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple solutions for this.

Try

Quite precise on the file name:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -File | Where-Object {$_.BaseName -match '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}_1\d+_\d*'}
```

OR less precise:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -File | Where-Object {($_.BaseName -split '_')[2] -match '^1'}
```

OR

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -File | Where-Object {$_.BaseName -match '1\d+_\d+$'}
```

OR

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -File | Where-Object {$_.BaseName -match '^[\d-]+_[\d-]+_1'}
```

Answer (score 0):

many thanks, its running )
where-object { $_[20] -eq "1" with this option can i sort files and copy )